# Linkedin API user shares statistics

Tags: linkedin-api

Maybe I'm missing something about the LinkedIn API endpoints, but it seems to me like Linkedin API does not have endpoint URL for **profile(wall) published post statistics** (likes,comments) or even organic search statistics (impressions,clicks,engagement). That is weird because company API has endpoints and decent documentation for their published content.

I know that since 2016 LinkedIn has changed its policies. I tried with `/v1/people/~/shares/updates` and `/v1/people/~/network/updates` (forum suggestion from 2014), but it gives errors 400 (Bad Request) and 403 (Forbidden),respectively. That happens because network API is allowed only through partnerships.

Is there a way to retrieve profile published content statistics through any endpoint or url from Linkedin?