# LinkedIn REST API extract analytics for personal posts

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to extract analytics data for personal posts from the LinkedIn API.
Appears you can get some useful data for company posts, e.g. https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/[companyid]/historical-status-update-statistics, but there's very little documentation on the API for personal posts.

(As an aside, LinkedIn should be ashamed of themselves for the lack of documentation on their API.)

Has anyone found a way to extract analytic data (e.g. impressions, clicks, video views etc.) for *personal* posts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I eventually found another SO question that answered my question: [Linkedin API user shares statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765702/linkedin-api-user-shares-statistics)

Seems LinkedIn have locked down most of their API unless you're a 'partner':
https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

LinkedIn, if you're listening, you're morons. This is 2017, locking developers out of your APIs is greedy and stupid.

But I guess my comments aren't going to change much.

Comment: Is this really still the case? In 2023?